# Performance implications with The name server failed to answer queries sent over TCP

Tags: tcp, dns, pingdom

when i checked my `DNS` helth with `pingom` tools i got this result "Name server  does not answer queries over TCP.". I know this is a requirement and i am about to implement this, but before doing this, i need to know whether this have any performance implications ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to consider things like this in your design:

1. setup the tcp connection time: on udp this time is zero: so you will like to keep the connection alive for a little while so that more queries can be served on same connection.
2. close the tcp connection time: on udp this time is zero
3. if you are going to keep the tcp connection for a longer duration (so that more queries can be sent from dns client), then you need to consider number of simultaneous tcp connections supported by the DNS server. If that reaches some high water mark, then start closing older connections: This part will need some good design work.

if you have taken these issues in account, then performance won't be a big issue though there will be always added time for 1/2 queries.